# Proving $\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos y}{1+\cos y}}=\frac{1-\cos y}{|\sin y|}$

Tags: trigonometry

I need help on this trigonometric identity problem:

> $$\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos y}{1+\cos y}}=\frac{1-\cos y}{|\sin y|}$$

I have tried using different formulas such as the half angle and double angle but I still can't manage to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Multiply the numerator and the denominator by $1-\cos(y)$.

Comment: For which side?

Comment: For the left side inside the square root.

Comment: Do you know that $1 - \cos y = 2 \sin^2 \frac y 2$ and $1 + \cos y = 2 \cos^2 \frac y 2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the square root, you can multiply numerator and denominator by $1\cos(y)$ with $y\neq 0+k\pi$. So, you have:
$$\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos y}{1+\cos y}\cdot\frac{1-\cos(y)}{1-\cos(y)}}=\sqrt{\frac{(1-\cos(y))^2}{1-\cos(y)^2}}$$
The numerator becomes simply $1-\cos(y)$, while for the denominator you have: $$1-\cos(y)^2=\sin(y)^2$$Note that in the numerator you don't have to introduce the absolute value because $1-\cos(y)\geq 0, \forall y \in R$ while in denominator you must have $|\sin(y)|$ ($\sin(y)$ can be positive or negative for $y\in R$).

In conclusion you have:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos y}{1+\cos y}}=\frac{1-\cos y}{|\sin y|}
$$